# Selenium automation PAF

Tags: paceautomationframework, ipaf

I am looking for automation testing on iOS, have got to know of `ipaf`.

Will Pace Automation Framework support automation on latest firefox browser.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the init configuration file please use below configuration to execute your test in firefox.

```
browser=FireFox
```

Answer (score 1):

PAF supports FireFox browser, so it should work on the latest FireFox browser.